# Is EE6 a good fit for our use case?

Tags: ee6

My company is looking at EE 6 as the basis for our SAS application.

In our business model, each company will have a backend to upload product information to, and customize forms and pages for their company.  We will have multiple companies each with it's own admin account on the backend.

On the front-end, users will search across all products, with the ability to apply filters based on product criteria.  We will be using Freeform Pro to handle forms.

Is this a good fit for the current version of EE?

Answer (score 1):

How many companies and/or member logins would you expect?

Generally, these requirements would pose no problems to EE6. Would EE be acting as the SAS, or more of a member login vehicle to feed data to another system?

Comment: We are looking at approximately 50 companies with product feeds. Average of about 200 products, with small outliers of 50 or less, and large as high as 5,000+.    The site's main focus is distributing data to various product feeds. However, we do want shoppers who find the site directly, to be able to filter and search based on brand/shipping time ext..

Comment: EE would have no issues serving that need. but the setup needs to be done cleverly. guess that's the case with any cms

Answer (score 0):

As Creative Arc suggested EE could be a good fit.

The only part that might need some thinking is "each company...[can] customise forms". EE has addons to manage custom email form creation but generally anyone with access can create forms and see other peoples forms. You might be able to work around that by providing premade form fields that the member can set up using a regular channel entry, or a custom module.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will not be a problem with EE using the multisite features, each company can have its own settings, but you are sharing some data with all of them like search and other features as it is using the same database. From a users' perspective, the front end, each one will be its own unique brand and company:

**Multiple Site Manager:**

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/msm/overview.html